# How do I test ios App use https for the communication with the server?

Tags: ios, https

In our project we want to make sure that the data communicating with the sever always transfer through the https.
As a tester, I want to test this work as expected. How do I test that in client side.
thanks

Comment: Unless you proxy all the iOS network request via a proxy there is no way to find out which calls a client does.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Info.plist temporarily.

Info.plist  -> Open As   ->   Source Code: NSAppTransportSecurity, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = NO.

So the client http is forbidden.

After the test, reset as before.